# How to extract keys from Map.Map?

Tags: haskell, functor

I wish to extract all the keys from a Map but I don't know how to access the keys. I had success grabbing all the values out of any foldable types such as Maps, but I am not sure how to access the keys inside the functor.

```
getVals :: (Foldable t) => t a -> [a]
getVals x = foldr (:) [] x
```

How do I define a function like this?

```
getKeys :: (Map k a) -> [k]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a `Map`'s keys with its `Foldable` instance. Instead, use `Data.Map.keys`.